# Multiple Upload File with Unusual Condition PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I have this add button to select the file inside a upload form field:

```js
$("#add_attachment").on('click', function() {
  var no_attachment = parseInt($('#noa').val()) + 1;
  $('#noa').val(no_attachment);
  $("#tbody_attachment").append("<tr><td bgcolor='#d9d9d9' class='td-data_1'><div class='col-xs-12'><input type='number' class='form-control' name='noa_save[]' id='noa_save' placeholder='No' value='" + no_attachment + "' /></div></td><td bgcolor='#d9d9d9' class='td-data_1'><div class='col-xs-12'><input type='file' class='form-control' name='attachment_save[]' id='attachment_save' placeholder='Attachment'/></div></td><td bgcolor='#d9d9d9' class='td-data_1'><div align='center'><input type='button' name='attachment' id='remove_attachment' value='Remove' style='font-size:16px; width: 98%;'/></div></td></tr>");
});

$("#tbody_attachment").on('click', '#remove_attachment', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  var no_attachment = $('#noa').val();
  $('#noa').val(parseInt(no_attachment) - 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="save_sop.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div align="center">
    <table class="table" id="t_attachment">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="10%" bgcolor="#8eb4e3" class="td-data_1">
            <div align="center">
              <font size="3dp"><strong>No</strong></font>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th bgcolor="#8eb4e3" class="td-data_1">
            <div align="center">
              <font size="3dp"><strong>Attachment</strong></font>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th width="10%" bgcolor="#8eb4e3" class="td-data_1">
            <div align="center">
              <font size="3dp"><strong>Button</strong></font>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tbody_attachment">
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#d9d9d9" class="td-data_1">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="noa" id="noa" placeholder="No" value="0" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td bgcolor="#d9d9d9" class="td-data_1">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div align="justify">
                <font size="3dp"><strong>Choose file after clicking Add button</strong></font>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td bgcolor="#d9d9d9" class="td-data_1">
            <div align="center"><input type="button" name="add_attachment" id="add_attachment" value="Add" style="font-size:16px; width: 98%;" /></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

You can run the code above to give an idea how's the form works.

And in the save_sop.php file, I have to upload the files that submitted from the previous form and also get the file name to be stored to MySQL database as a JSON array value.

Here's the code so far in the save_sop.php file:

```html
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  include 'con.php';
  
  $total_attachment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['noa']);
  $attachment["no"] = $_POST['noa_save'];
  
  foreach($_FILES['attachment_save']['name'] as $filename) {

        $imgFile = $filename;
        $tmp_dir = $_FILES['attachment_save']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['attachment_save']['size'];

        $folder = 'sop/attachment/'; // upload directory
        $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension
        // valid image extensions
        $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions
        // rename uploading image
        $img = rand(1000, 1000000) . "." . $imgExt; //generate the random file name
        // allow valid image file formats
        if (in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)) {
        // Check file size '50MB'
            if ($imgSize < 5000000) {
                //move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $folder . $img);
            } else {
                $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            }
        } else {
            $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        }

        echo "Generated File Name: " . $img . "<hr />";
        $attachment['attachment'] = $img;
        
    }
    
    $attachment_save = json_encode($attachment, true);
    echo $attachment_save;
  
}

?>
```

When the echo $attachment_save called, the result I get is below.

```html
Generated File Name: 430609.jpg
<hr />
Generated File Name: 575033.jpg
<hr />
{"no":["1","2"],"attachment":"575033.jpg"}
```

Inside foreach loop, I called **echo "Generated File Name:" . $img;** I do get the result as expected, but in the attachment array, I only get one filename instead of two.

I need to get two file name value inside the attachment['attachment'] array. The result expected should be:

```html
{"no":["1","2"],"attachment":["430609.jpg", "575033.jpg"]}
```

Can anybody help me with this? thanks in advance.
Regards.

Comment: `$attachment['attachment'] = $img;` You overwrite that value with every iteration. Last one wins

Comment: @kerbholz hi there, I think you are correct. As I try over and over again, seems like the last the value will be always the last foreach value. How do I prevent this? I need to make it show all of the data instead of showing the last one. thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

the answer lies on
**$attachment. Instead of $attachment['attachment'] = $img;**

it should be
**$attachment['attachment'][] = $img;**

and it's working perfectly.